# Ligar a Localização Atual Android Studio

Tags: android, maps

Estou desenvolvendo um `App Android` que contem um mapa e que pega a minha localização, porem em alguns aparelhos ele não ativa essa função, para que funcione é preciso clicar no botão `Local` por exemplo `Samsung J5`. Como posso fazer para que esse botão se ative automaticamente ao abrir o mapa?

> Obs:É um mapa simples, somente alguns marcadores e minha localização.

A partir do `Android 6.0` já consigo a permissão para abrir o mapa na posição demarcada, somente o meu local não. Coloquei link com o imagem do que quero que ligue automaticamente. Lembrando que quando abro o mapa ele pede permissão mas não ativa o local só o mapa.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxA6O.jpg)

Esse é meu mapa:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,
                        "Atenção! Ative o Local...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,
                        "Permissão de Localização Negada, ...:(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // Tipo do Mapa
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    //Minha Posição Atual
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Posicao inicial onde o mapa abre
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(-27.3246787, -53.4387937), (float) 14.5));

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-27.356857, -53.396316);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


    LatLng fw = new LatLng(-27.369282, -53.402667);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(fw)
            .title("Marker in Sydney")
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer dar foco no mapa no local em que criou o marker (-27.3246787, -53.4387937) ou na sua posição atual do gps do dispositivo do usuário?

Comment: Quero que ligue o botão Local que nem da imagem https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxA6O.jpg desse link

Comment: Desculpa Rafa, não entendi onde fica esse botão, seria na área de configurações do celular? É aquele botão que ativa ou desativa o serviço de localização?

Comment: Isso mesmo, já revirei na net e não encontrei nada que ative o botão, encontrei alguns  exemplos como Ativar wifi por exemplo, mas esse não encontrei nada

Comment: Então Rafa, entendi. Acho que não existe uma API pública e confiável para isso, você terá que delegar essa tarefa ao usuário. O máximo que você pode fazer de forma confiável é levar o usuário para a tela de configurações de localização e instruir ele a ativar o serviço de localização.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Então, você não pode ativar a "Fine Location" do smartphone do seu usuário. Isso vai contra as boas práticas de Android, onde o software não pode interagir com o hardware sem que o usuário permita isso ativamente (clicando em um botão, por exemplo)

Pelo que estou vendo do seu app a 'Fine Location' é bem importante, certo?

Esse método aqui resolve seu problema de uma maneira elegante:

```
private void createNoGpsDialog(){
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mNoGpsDialog = builder.setMessage("Por favor ative seu GPS para usar esse aplicativo.")
                .setPositiveButton("Ativar", dialogClickListener)
                .create();
        mNoGpsDialog.show();

    }
```

Basicamente você cria um Dialog e pede para seu usuário para ativar o GPS dele. Ai, quando ele clica em "Ativar" ele irá para os "Settings" do telefone e pode ativar o GPS.

Coloca isso dentro do seu onCreate ou do seu onMapReady e vai funcionar bacana.

Comment: Sensacional, muito bom mesmo eu não havia pensado nisso, funcionou muito bem, porem ele pede toda vez que entro no mapa para ativar mesmo já estando ativo, como eu poderia corrigir isso?

Comment: Consegui resolver com isso, fiz um teste e tratamento de exceção. Muito obrigado me ajudou muito mesmo. Forte Abraço
try {
            checkGps();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            createNoGpsDialog();
        }
//-----------------------------------
    public void checkGps() throws Exception
    {
        LocationManager manager;

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            throw new Exception("gps off");

        }
    }